# Using .resx files for localized resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

I have to rewrite a web application which uses localized resources (strings). But this application doesn't use .resx files, instead all localized strings are in the database. In the Application_Start method, it loads all thoses localized strings and put them in hashtables, this hashtables are in fact "static public" properties of a "static public" class. Application pages uses this Hashtables to retrieve localized strings, the current culture is mentionned in a Session variable.

I know this is not the "natural" way to store and retrieve localized resource. The framework .NET favor usage of .resx files and the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture for storing the current culture. I would use this if I was developing from scratch, but in my case the solution above is already there and the new solution requires some work.

What do I gain from using the .resx files, is the extra effort justified ?

Thanks

EDIT: I think my question is different from the metionned one, since in my case there is already a working solution and I want to know if the effort is justified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the benefits of resource(.resx) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134018/what-are-the-benefits-of-resource-resx-files)

Answer (score 2):

I would think you should get a significant performance increase in application startup.

However, on the down side, you would lose the ability to edit the resource strings without rebuilding the web application.

It really depends on which you value more, the volatility of the resource strings and whether the current application startup performance is causing a problem.